# Convert normal string to datetime format

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to convert normal string **5pm** into `2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z` format?

I have got this from backend but Im using timepicker in antd. It only accepts `2022-04-20T17:00:00.000Z` format and it is in string format in my DB.

Comment: what does new Date(dbDate) gives you?

Comment: What exactly did you get from the backend? Just 5pm?

Comment: yes only 5pm.Because db it written as string type

Comment: This is not possible unless you know what timezone "5pm" refers to; the format you're converting to is UTC-based.

Answer (score -1):

This should consistently give you the current date with the time attached

```js
function convertToISO(timeString) {
  const [hour12, ampm] = timeString.split(/(?=[ap]m$)/i)
  const hour = hour12 % 12 + (ampm.toLowerCase() === 'pm' ? 12 : 0)
  const date = new Date()
  // Set time, adjusted for time zone
  date.setHours(hour, -date.getTimezoneOffset(), 0, 0)
  return date.toISOString()
}

console.log(convertToISO('5pm'))
```

Comment: This returns 5pm in UTC, which may or may not be the timezone they intended